# BufferedReader, detecting if there is text left to read

Tags: java, bufferedreader, java-io

I'm running a thread and everytime it runs, It should be checking to see if there is a new line to read from the `BufferedReader` although, it gets stuck waiting for a line to exist, thus halting the entire code.

```
if((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(inputLine);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, inputLine);
}
```

Is there a way to better check if there is text in a `BufferedReader` to be read?

Comment: Why? It will block if there's no data. What else are you going to do instead?

Comment: Have you tried `BufferedReader#ready()` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#ready()?

Comment: I don't think that `ready()` would answer that need. `ready()` would tell him whether there's something in the buffer; it won't tell him whether there's a full line to read. `readLine()` will still enter a waiting state, won't it?

Comment: ready fixed it, thanks guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no easy way to do that.  `BufferedReader` has a `ready` call, but that only applies to the `read` calls, not the `readLine` call.  If you really want a `readLine` that's guaranteed not to block, you must implement it yourself using `read` and maintaining a `char` buffer yourself.

Comment: so if I do ready() that will skip over it if there is no text in there? the readlLine was just so I could use spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you check if it's ready to be read first? Just use [`bufferedReader.ready()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#ready%28%29).

**Edit:**

`ready` won't tell you if you have a line ready, it will just tell you that there is something to be read. However, if you are expecting to get a line then this will work for you. The idea would be, first check if it's ready, and then read the line, in this way the thread won't be hanging there when there is absolutely nothing to read.

Comment: `ready()` will return `true` but `readLine()` might still block, if the buffer contains characters none of which is a line terminator.

Comment: It's not reliable in general (allowed to give false negatives), and in any case, only checks that there's at least one character available, not a full line.

Answer (score 0):

The `readLine` method will block unless it can read an entire line (delimited by a line-terminating character), or the end of input has been reached:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()

The case you're describing is that the end of input hasn't yet been reached, but there's not enough characters in the buffer to constitute a "line" (that is, a series of characters ended by a line terminator).

You will have to go lower than the `readLine` level for that, possibly to the Stream level itself. `InputStream` has a method called `available()`, which would answer your needs.